# JSON Serializing Scala Case Class to only strings and ints

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have a need to serialize a handful of case classes to only strings and ints. Meaning, if there's a nested type, it gets serialized as the stringified version of a JSON object, not a JSON object.

Example:

```
case class Deepest(someNum: Int)
case class Inner(superDeep: Deepest)
case class Outer(aValue: Int, aNestedValue: Inner)
```

Serializing an instance of `Outer` Would result in (or something similar)

```
{
    "Outer": {
        "aValue": 5,
        "aNestedValue": "{ \"superDeep\": .... }"
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible I guess, if you write a custom `Writes[Outer]` in Play-Json for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) is the simplest and most efficient way to do it with Scala.

Add dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // Use the %%% operator instead of %% for Scala.js  
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core"   % "2.12.0",
  // Use the "provided" scope instead when the "compile-internal" scope is not supported  
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "2.12.0" % "compile-internal"
)
```

Use a custom codec from this snippet:

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._

object Example01 {
  sealed trait Message
  case class Deepest(someNum: Int)
  case class Inner(superDeep: Deepest)
  case class Outer(aValue: Int, aNestedValue: Inner) extends Message

  implicit val innerCodec: JsonValueCodec[Inner] = new JsonValueCodec[Inner] {
    private val codec: JsonValueCodec[Inner] = JsonCodecMaker.make

    override def decodeValue(in: JsonReader, default: Inner): Inner =
      readFromStringReentrant(in.readString(null))(codec)

    override def encodeValue(x: Inner, out: JsonWriter): Unit =
      out.writeVal(writeToStringReentrant(x)(codec))

    override def nullValue: Inner = null
  }
  implicit val messageCodec: JsonValueCodec[Message] =
    JsonCodecMaker.make(CodecMakerConfig.withDiscriminatorFieldName(None))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val message = readFromString[Message](
    """{
      |    "Outer": {
      |        "aValue": 5,
      |        "aNestedValue": "{ \"superDeep\": { \"someNum\": 1 } }"
      |    }
      |}""".stripMargin)
    println(writeToString[Message](message, WriterConfig.withIndentionStep(4)))
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "Outer": {
        "aValue": 5,
        "aNestedValue": "{\"superDeep\":{\"someNum\":1}}"
    }
}
```

If more than one type should be stringified you can define a function that takes a regular codec and return a codec that stringify output of original one:

```
  def makeStringifyingCodec[A](codec: JsonValueCodec[A]): JsonValueCodec[A] = 
    new JsonValueCodec[A] {
      override def decodeValue(in: JsonReader, default: A): A =
        readFromStringReentrant(in.readString(null))(codec)

      override def encodeValue(x: A, out: JsonWriter): Unit =
        out.writeVal(writeToStringReentrant(x)(codec))

      override def nullValue: A = null.asInstanceOf[A]
    }
```

And use it for field types of the `Outer` class:

```
implicit val innerCodec: JsonValueCodec[Inner] = 
  makeStringifyingCodec(JsonCodecMaker.make[Inner])
implicit val messageCodec: JsonValueCodec[Message] = 
  JsonCodecMaker.make(CodecMakerConfig.withDiscriminatorFieldName(None))
```